# Using observables (map?) to load fbx in threejs

Tags: angular, typescript, three.js

I am using three.js to display some 3D-meshes in the browser, but I need to call a function that only applies to some elements after they have been loaded. Some models only need to be imported, while others need an operation executed on them as well. There is some general loading code that adds the object to the scene. But for one particular mesh I need to add some panels on the inside (the panel is a submesh of the fbx) with a duplicate function I have written. I think I would need an observer declared on load start, but there is no event for this... and the load function returns void.

My question is: How do I add a function to the onLoad callback (using observable or other means) where I can in that observable access the object: THREE:Group created in the load function.

Expected flow: I am hoping to have an observable for each mesh that is being loaded, when the load finishes, I can execute a function that I have specified for that specific observable.

UPDATE: Code changes to better reflect what I am trying to achieve. The current behaviour works, but feels dirty.

```js
load( url: string, onLoad: ( object: Group ) => void, onProgress?: ( event: ProgressEvent ) => void, onError?: ( event: ErrorEvent ) => void ) : void;
```

```js
    loadFBX = (name: string, materials: TextureMapper[], onComplete, raycastable: boolean = true) => {
        MeshLoader.loader.load('../../assets/meshes/' + name + '.fbx', (object: THREE.Group) => {
            // some general irrelevant loader code...
            onComplete();
        });
    }
```

Wanted behaviour could be something like this, where the object is captured to execute the function. But I am struggling to find a solution to this.

```js
    this.loader.loadFBX('Loggia-panel', [
      { meshName: 'Loggia-frame', material: 'aluminium' },
      { meshName: 'Loggia-board', material: 'woodLight' }],
      () => {
        const mesh = this.scene.getObjectByName('Loggia-board');
        for (const object of MeshManipulator.array(mesh, 33, new Vector3(0, 0, 2))) {
          mesh.parent.add(object);
        }

        mesh.parent.position.set(-70, 0, -55);
        this.scene.add(MeshManipulator.duplicate(mesh.parent, new Vector3(70, 0, -55)));
      });
```

UPDATE: I am trying an approach where I can return an observable, but am unsure how I can assign it and return it in this manner... I am still learning how these observables work. But figured out that the observable can be returned and the observer will handle an event when I tell it to in the onComplete function.

```js
    loadFBX = (fileName: string): Observable<Object3D> => {
        MeshLoader.loader.load('../../assets/meshes/' + fileName + '.FBX', (object: THREE.Group) => {
            // set the object3D observable and notify observer to fire event
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public loaderObservable(fbxUrl: string): Observable<any> {
return new Observable((subscriber) => {
    loader.load(
      fbxUrl,
      (fbx) => {
        subscriber.next(fbx);
        subscriber.complete();
      },
      (event: ProgressEvent<EventTarget>) => {},
      (event) => subscriber.error(event),
    );
});}
```

Try this approach. Consider this is only example to transform all loader callback in a observable method.